# Running Spring cloud contract test in separate gradle task

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I want to run spring cloud contract test cases as part of seperate gradle task named as "asyncContractTestCases" I have configured contract task as below :

```
contracts { 
       generatedTestSourcesDir = project.file('src/contracttest/async/provider/java')
       basePackageForTests='com.test.producer'
       baseClassForTests="com.test.producer.MessagingContractTests"
   }
```

and created a seperate gradle task to execute these test cases but still these test cases execute with gradle test ( as part of JUNITS). how not to run spring cloud contract test cases as part of junits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the configuration of Gradle's test execution. You can exclude the contract tests by default and include them in your task

```
test {
    description = "Task to run unit and integration tests"
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    exclude '**/producer/**'
}

task asyncContractTestCases(type: Test) {
    description = "Task to run contract tests"
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    include '**/producer/**'
}
```